# How select two value in picker? (KIF)

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ui-testing, kif, kif-framework

I have picker. Picker have 2 column. How select two value in picker use KIF?
Sample:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbwj2.png

I'm tried use next:

```
 NSArray *date = @[@"Honda", @"Civic"];
 [tester selectDatePickerValue:date];
```

And:

```
 [tester selectPickerViewRowWithTitle:@"Honda" inComponent:0];
```

And:

```
[tester selectPickerViewRowsWithTitles:@[@"Toyota", @"Land Cruiser"]];
```

Always comes out error:

> The UIDatePicker does not have the expected column count

Nothing helped. Maybe I'm somewhere missed something?

Comment: Your code that calls `[tester selectPickerViewRowWithTitle:@"Honda" inComponent:0];` is correct. Can you post a sample project of something that doesn't work?

Comment: @JimPuls can not show the project (security policy of the company). I've been trying to do this, and I can not fix it.